# Websites don't always load immediately

Tags: windows-10, performance, internet, website

I'm experiencing a strange issue in all of my browsers (Opera, Chrome, Edge) by websites not always loading immediately. Sometimes they do, other times I have to wait a couple of seconds. I can see the website's icon in the address bar so the DNS has been resolved pretty quickly, but then it just hangs there and waits for who knows what.

I've already did the follwing:

- replaced the WiFi with a CAT6 cable and have a 1Gbit connection with the router
- did all the `ipconfig` stuff with flushing dns
- restarting the ethernet adapter
- restarting the router
- restarting the PC
- clearing all cookies & removing everything from the cache
- used different DNSes like the original one by the internet provider and by Google, OpenDNS or CloudFire
- disabling the firewall (by ESET)
- creating a new profile
- opening websites in the incodnito mode
- opening websites without any extensions in a clean browser
- updating drivers
- testing the link speed on speed test which is always at the top of what my connection can handle
- blocking 3rd-party cookies

What else can I try?

My hardware is:

- CPU i7-7700 3.60GHz
- 64GB RAM
- Intel Ethernet Connection I219-LM
- Samsung SSD 850 PRO

Comment: Perhaps your system is trying to contact these sites over IPv6.

Comment: @Bib the next experiment has started with IPv6 disabled...

Comment: Questions: (1) Did you look for an update to the router's firmware? (2) Does it only happen from your computer, and have you tried other computers at your place? (3) If this is a laptop, did you try elsewhere than at your place?